# ITEXT 7.0.4 Application goes in infinte loop when length of data increases

Tags: java, spring-mvc, itext, itext7

I am having an issue creating PDF using iTEXT-7.0.4 when data in table row increases to a certain limit, The program goes in an infinite loop. I am providing the appropriate screenshot. Please tell me if you need anything other than this. I am using Spring MVC 3 in my project.

**StudentReportCard.java**

```
private void getStudentAndInstituteDetailsReport(Document doc, StudentReportCardJson reportCardJson, Institution institute) {
        Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[] { 80, 20 })).useAllAvailableWidth();
        table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
        logger.info("inside main detail table");
        Table studentDetTable = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[] { 60 }), true).useAllAvailableWidth();
        logger.info("inside student detail table");
        studentDetTable.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(60));
        studentDetTable.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        logger.info("inside institute detail table");
        Table instituteDetTable = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[] { 20 })).useAllAvailableWidth();
        instituteDetTable.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(30));
        instituteDetTable.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        Paragraph reportDate = new Paragraph("Report Date: ").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).setFontSize(8f).setFontColor(Color.BLACK).setBold();
        Paragraph dateValue = new Paragraph(Utilities.getDisplaySqlDateInString(Utilities.getCurrentDate())).setFontSize(8f).setFontColor(Color.BLACK);

        studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(0, 1).add(getHeadingAndTextFormatting("Student Name: ", reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getStudent_name())).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        if (institute.getCourse_structure_flag() == 1) {
            studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(1, 1).add(getHeadingAndTextFormatting("Course(s): ", reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getAssignedCourses())).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        } else {
            studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(0, 1).add("").setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        }
    // This line of code creates infinite loop
        if (Utilities.isNotBlank(reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned())) {
            studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(7, 1).add(getHeadingAndTextFormatting("Subject(s): ", reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned())).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        }
        if (Utilities.isNotBlank(reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getStudent_phone())) {
            studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(0, 1).add(getHeadingAndTextFormatting("Contact No.: ", reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getStudent_phone())).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        }
        if (Utilities.isNotBlank(reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getStudent_email())) {
            studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(0, 1).add(getHeadingAndTextFormatting("Email ID: ", reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getStudent_email())).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        }
        studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(0, 1).add(getHeadingAndTextFormatting("Joining Date: ", reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getDoj())).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(0, 1).add(new Paragraph().add(reportDate).add(dateValue)).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        Style style = new Style();
        style.setFontColor(Color.BLACK).setFontSize(8f).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
        Cell instituteLogoCell = new Cell();
        if (Utilities.isNotBlank(institute.getLogo_url())) {
            ImageData data = null;
            try {
                data = ImageDataFactory.create(institute.getLogo_url());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (data != null) {
                Image img = new Image(data);
                img.scaleAbsolute(60f, 30f);
                instituteLogoCell.add(img).setPaddingLeft(189f).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
                // instituteLogoCell.setPaddingLeft(187f);
            }
        } else {
            instituteLogoCell.add("").setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
        }
        instituteDetTable.addCell(instituteLogoCell);
        instituteDetTable.addCell(new Cell(0, 1).add(institute.getInstitute_name()).addStyle(style).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        instituteDetTable.addCell(new Cell(0, 1).add(institute.getInstitute_primary_email()).addStyle(style).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        instituteDetTable.addCell(new Cell(0, 1).add(institute.getInstitute_primary_phone()).addStyle(style).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(studentDetTable).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        logger.info("end student det table");
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(instituteDetTable).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        logger.info("end institute det table");
        doc.add(table);
        logger.info("end main det table");
    }

     private Paragraph getHeadingAndTextFormatting(String heading, String value) {
        Style style = new Style();
        style.setFontColor(Color.BLACK);
        style.setFontSize(7f);
        Paragraph headingValue = new Paragraph(heading).setFontColor(new DeviceRgb(107, 104, 132)).setFontSize(7f).setBold().setMarginBottom(0.0f).setMarginTop(0.0f);
        Paragraph text = new Paragraph(value).addStyle(style).setMarginBottom(0.0f).setMarginTop(0.0f);
        return new Paragraph().add(headingValue).add(text).setFixedLeading(16);
    }
```

In above code **reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned()** makes my PDF into infinite loop

This is the data coming in above code **data structure & algorithms, chemistry, OOP's,Artificial Intelligence Operations & Management,maths, physics, Software Testing & automation testing, Java , DS**.

Comment: So what happens in `reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned()` and what do you mean the PDF is in infinite loop? From the code provided, there is no loop at all.

Comment: 7.0.4 is an early itext 7 version. Have you tried with newer version? Probably you ran into a bug which has been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: That being said, do I understand you correctly that you mean the line `if (Utilities.isNotBlank(reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned())) {` in your comment *This line of code creates infinite loop*?

Comment: @samabcde there is no loop in my code that I know but I am trying to say that PDF is generating continuously which slows down the server down

Comment: @mkl no I haven't  tried with newer version.
Yes line of code (Utilities.isNotBlank(reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned()))
makes PDF keeps generating on continuously which slowed down the server

Comment: *"Yes line of code (Utilities.isNotBlank(reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned())) makes PDF keeps generating on continuously which slowed down the server"* - But there is no iText code in that line (unless your application architecture is extremely weird). Thus, you should look into your JSON library and `Utilities` for the cause of your problem.

Comment: @samabcde @mkl as my code gets true for `(Utilities.isNotBlank(reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned())) {` while performing operation beneath it i.e, `studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(7, 1).add(getHeadingAndTextFormatting("Subject(s): ", reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned())).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));` which creates an infinte loop.

Comment: Is the program keep running in line `studentDetTable.addCell(new Cell(7, 1).add(getHeadingAndTextFormatting("Subject(s): ", reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned())).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));` and not execute remaining line, or just running that line very slow? Add some log after that line if you are not sure.

Comment: @MeghaTayal *"as my code gets true for ... while performing operation beneath it i.e,  ... which creates an infinte loop."* - That's different from what you write in your question. You might want to edit it. That being said, what *is* the content of `reportCardJson.getStudentJson().getBatchesAssigned()` which brings iText to a halt? We'd need Data that allows reproducing the issue. Furthermore, why do you add row spans of 7 rows here for a table with only a single column?